# Call function before page postback in Asp.Net using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I needed to call a function before postback in Asp.Net. Is there anyway to do this using JQuery?

Comment: Please also post code from which control you want to call the function and what the function will do on call?

Comment: @Tushar it's not working

Comment: @Suprabhat assume it's a simple javascript function

Comment: Do tou want to perform logic when a user clicks a button and before the postback?

Comment: @Saasen No. Actually I want to know is there any way to do this without specific element postback, it will call any postback event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following jQuery script in your code to call your function in the beginRequest. You must set the **AutoPostBack** property of those controls to true for which you want to initiate this before callback function call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(function (source, args) {
        // YOUR FUNCTION CALL HERE such as display processing/loading prompt/div
    });
    prm.add_endRequest(function (source, args) {
        // any other code you want to execute after the post back finishes such as hiding processing/loading prompt/div
    });
});
</script>
```

Be sure to add a **ScriptManager and UpdatePanel** to your page. For more details you may check this [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397432(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: It seems the event is not triggered for AutoPostBack, is there another event for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        // do the extra stuff here
        //return true to submit the form
        //return false if do not want to submit form
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't you think that `$("form").submit(function()` will run only if we click the submit button on the form and not on any other button

Answer (score 0):

Example of calling a jquery function on server side with Page_Load event:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
'"Expandir Compras" its the Unique identifier of the script code
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "Expandir Compras", "$('#collapseCompras').collapse('show');", True)
End Sub
```

Maybe you can do something similar with the right event (Save Changes, Pre Load, Data Binding, etc). Hope it helps!